# How can we set the parbox width to fractional multiple of horizontal unit of tikzpicture?

Tags: tikz-pgf

In the following code, I set the horizontal unit of `tikzpicture` to `1/20` of the width of an image. I also want to use `\parbox` with a fractional multiple of this unit as its width.

```
\documentclass[tikz,10pt,dvipsnames,border=0cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\def\M{10}% columns
\def\N{10}% rows
\def\scale{1}% scale
\def\filename{example-image-a.pdf}% filename


\def\mygrid{%
    \draw[help lines,red,step=.1,ForestGreen!50](-\M,-\N) grid (\M,\N); 
    \draw[help lines,red,step=1](-\M,-\N) grid (\M,\N);
    \foreach \x in{-\M,...,\M}{\node[anchor=south] at (\x,\N){\x};}
    \foreach \y in{-\N,...,\N}{\node[anchor=east] at (-\M,\y){\y};}
}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\newsavebox\IBox
\savebox\IBox{\includegraphics[scale=\scale,page=1]{\filename}}



\newif\ifgrid
\gridtrue
\gridfalse



\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0,x=.5\wd\IBox/\M\relax,y=.5\ht\IBox/\N\relax]
    \node (image) at (0,0) {\usebox\IBox};
    \tikzset{anchor=base west}

    \node at (-8,1.6) {\parbox{4cm}{\color{red} In PSTricks we trust. Why?}};   % I want 4 times of the horizontal unit instead of 4 cm.

    \ifgrid
        \mygrid
    \fi
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How to do so?

Comment: What about using `let` to extract the `x` component of `(1,0)`? I'll try in a minute...

Comment: Unless there is a special reason for explicitly using `\parbox`, I'd encourage the use of the `text width` key which would internally insert a `minipage` for the node contents. It parses its argument so you could say `text width=4*\csname pgf@xx\endcsname` (`\pgf@xx` is the internal x-component of the prevailing x-vector). Also you could use `text=red` instead of `\color{red}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to do the trick (requires the `calc` tikz library):

```
\path let \p1 = (4,0) in node at (-8,1.6) {\parbox{\x1}{\color{red} In PSTricks we trust. Why?}};
```

It measures "4×(x unit)" by using the `let` operation binding `\p1` to the point `(4,0)` (note the absence of dimension units).
Then we extract its x-component by doing `\x1` which expands to the correct dimension.

A similar result can be obtained using PGF directly:

```
\newdimen\myunit
\pgfextractx{\myunit}{\pgfpointxy{1}{0}}
\node at (-8,1.6) {\parbox{4\myunit}{\color{red} In PSTricks we trust. Why?}};
```